# Extract items of IEnumerable<T> whose Key-Value is equal to one of the KeyValues in IEnumerable<U>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections, ienumerable

I want to extract all items of an IEnumerable sequence whose Key-Value is equal to one of the Key-Values in another IEnumerable sequence.
Please consider the first sequence is of Type 'T', where T is:

```
class T
{
    int SpecificValue;
    // other payload
}
```

and the second sequence is of Type 'U', where U is:

```
class U
{
    int SpecificValueOfSameType;
    // other payload (different from class T)
}
```

Is it possible?

As a side node: I used the term "Key"-Value, but there's no guarantee that this value is unique in either of both sequences. It should just help to explain my requirements a little bit more in detail. In real code, I can imagine there's some kind of Compare-Func parameter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Ts.Where(t => Us.Select(u => u.SpecificValueOfSameType).Contains(t.SpecificValue))
```

Comment: That's what I've already got. Thought there is something mroe straightforward. (Btw. I think you wanted to write ".Contains(t.SpecificValue)". So, "t", instead of "y").

Comment: another way is to use join, but I try to avoid joins if I only need to select items from one collection; fixed the "t" thx

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're looking for a [`Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx).

```
ts.Join(us, t => t.SpecificValue, u => u.SpecificValueOfSameType, (t, u) => new Something)
```

Comment: No, I don't want to merge/zip these both collections. I just want extract values from one collection depending on conditions related to another one.

Comment: Won't such a join introduce duplicates?   {1, 1, 2, 2} matched to {1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2} = 12 results.  Should be 4 results.

Answer (score 1):

As K Ivanov has shown, you can use `Contains` - but if your collection is fairly large, you'd be best off putting them in a HashSet first:

```
var keys = new HashSet<T>(us.Select(u => u.SpecificValueOfSameType));
var query = ts.Where(t => keys.Contains(t.SpecificValue));
```

EDIT: I'd missed the fact that there could be duplicate keys in either collection. That's fine with the above code, but wouldn't work well with a join (at least, not without a Distinct call too).

It's not entirely clear what you mean by a "Compare-Func" parameter. If that's just a way of extracting the key from the sequence, that's fine. If it's a function to compare the equality of two keys, that's a different matter. That would mean you couldn't mean hashing.

Answer (score 0):

> there's no guarantee that this value is unique in either of both sequences.

Well, that makes it clear that you want to stay away from most joins.

How about a GroupJoin?  This type of join won't introduce duplication when there are multiple matches.

```
from t in tSource
join u in uSource
  on t.SpecificValue
  equals u.SpecificValueOfSameType
  into g
where g.Any()
select t;
```

also written as:

```
tSource.GroupJoin(uSource,
  t => t.SpecificValue,
  u => u.SpecificValueOfSameType,
  (t, g) => new {t, g})
.Where(x => x.g.Any())
.Select(x => x.t)
```

Comment: So, when it "won't introduce duplication", it will result in distinct values only? That's not what I'm after. This value isn't unique, but that doesn't mean that two records with the same value are representing the same entity.